# How do I automate removal and re-enabling overscan as I move the pi between HDMI and TV?

Tags: raspbian, linux, hdmi, display, config.txt

I use my Pi (with raspbian) in two locations, at the desk I have a DVI-D monitor hooked to the HDMI output and in the livingroom there is a big old thick television using PAL composite.. I would like to automatically remove the borders that the TV needs when using the monitor and vice versa. As it is now I have to edit config.txt and reboot (i.e boot twice) every time I move the Pi from one room to the other.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could automate the action suggested above with a script.

```
if /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -s | grep 'NTSC\|PAL'; then
  echo $(hostname) is running Composite
else
  echo $(hostname) is running hdmi
fi
```

Replace the echo lines with the desired adjustments

Answer (score 2):

Try adjusting the left and right margins using the [fbset](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_fbset.htm) command:

```
fbset -left xxx -right yyyy
```

Where xxx is the left margin in pixels and yyy is the right margin in pixels.

```
fbset -left 0 -right 0
```

Should set the left and right margins to zero

I have used this command to change the screen resolution on my Pi using a Motorola Lapdock as my HDMI display.

Comment: Thanks, but this does nothing on my LCD(dvi-D) monitor when issued with sudo from an xterm..

Comment: What does `fbset` and `tvservice -s` show?